# mongodb extension not working for MAMP in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, mamp, php-ini

I am on `MAMP` platform. My `Apache server` was up and running.

Then, I've install `mongo-php-driver` using **`homebrew`** by following the instructions on this link http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php for installation process.

After installation, i loaded extension in  my `php.ini` but both ways it fails to load.

> extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-mongodb/mongodb.so"
>                            or
>     extension=mongodb.so

I tried restarting MAMP, but Apache won't start. I also following  this thread for a solution:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/681 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/682

**My Environment:**

**macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

MAMP 4.2

PHP 5.6.30**

Can anyone give me a clear answer and guide me how i use mongodb in my MAMAP. I am trying to solve it for last 3 days and i am tired.

Comment: What is the specific error message associated with the issue?

Comment: Please go over the link you will find it https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/682

Comment: Improved content formatting and added relevant tags